# Calcurse can't sync with Nextcloud

Tags: https, command-line, calendar, config, nextcloud

Hello I've recently setup a nextcloud instance with a calendar and wanted to sync my calcurse with it.

This is my calcurse-caldav config(password, username and hostname obviously changed):

```
[General]
Binary = calcurse
Hostname = nextcloud.example.com/nextcloud
Path = remote.php/dav/
AuthMethod = basic
HTTPS = Yes 
DryRun = No  
Verbose = Yes

[Auth]
Username = BestUsername
Password = SuperSecretPassword
```

I get the following error though:

```
╰─$ calcurse-caldav --init keep-remote
Connecting to nextcloud.example.com/nextcloud...
Removing all local calcurse objects...
error: The server at nextcloud.example.com/nextcloud replied with HTTP status
error: code 415 (Unsupported Media Type) while trying to access
error: https://nextcloud.example.com/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/.
```

I strongly suspect that there is something wrong with my config but I can't understand what as this config worked perfectly with Calibre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it: the correct way to configure it is the following:

```
Hostname = nextcloud.example.com
Path = /nextcloud/remote.php/dav/calendars/$USERNAME/personal
```